# Email alert if there is any 502 or 500 error logged in Elastic-search

Tags: elasticsearch, devops

Is there any tool, Which i can use/configure over my ELK Stack where i get email alert if any we get any error on out website. Many a times it happened that at night we get some error but no one looks in to that and later it become a big problem. I'm just looking for a tool which can send alert every 6 hours or something.

Comment: open source tool? As far as I know elastic licence include Watches for alerting email.

Comment: Yes, an opensource tool which can help me to do some custom stuff later if required as much i know watchers will not give that much details

Answer (score 0):

Use X-pack and enable the watchers configuration.

Comment: but how exactly ? I have an index created with the help of metricbeats and with all the data, but still could not find how to configure it